# django connection from Linux to MS SQL Server on Windows

Tags: sql-server, django

I have an issue to connect to MS SQL Server on Windows on my computer from VirtualBox, where linux is installed. What connection string should I have in django settings in DATABASES{}?
Will i be able to see my computer form virtual box using its ip address?

Comment: Are you able to ping your SQL Server host from the virtual Linux? Make sure that there is a connection between the guest OS and host OS. http://house9.blogspot.com/2011/04/ping-guest-os-from-host-os-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. Server didn't respond on port 1433. And i had TCP\IP option in SQL Server Configuration Manager "Enabled".
BUT I Entered propertites of TCP\IP in manager and set PORT: 1433 and activated TCP\IP in its properties. Then connection was established.